# Is there a method to programatically add several RouteAttributes to a given ControllerModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Currently I'm using the code below to programmatically set all of my api routes which works fine.

What I'd like to achieve is programmatically setting 2 routes for each action without manually setting `RouteAttribute("MY_ROUTE")` twice on every action .

This is how I'm currently setting the routes.

```cs
public static void Map(ControllerModel model)
{
    string templatePrefix = "api/services/app";
    ...
    if (AppStore.Contains(model.ControllerName))
        templatePrefix = "api/services/AppStore";
    ...
    foreach (var action in model.Actions)
    {
        var verb = ProxyScriptingHelper.GetConventionalVerbForMethodName(action.ActionName);
        var constraint = new HttpMethodActionConstraint(new List<string> { verb });

        foreach (var selector in action.Selectors)
        {
            selector.ActionConstraints.Add(constraint);
            selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel(new RouteAttribute($"{templatePrefix.EnsureEndsWith('/')}{action.Controller.ControllerName}/{action.ActionName}"));
        }
    }
}
```

Ive tried `AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributedRouteModel` but that joins the route strings together, not what I was expecting.

With the code above, all `AppStore` controller actions become

```
api/services/AppStore/getApps1
api/services/AppStore/getApps2
api/services/AppStore/getApps3
```

The results i would like get are

```
api/services/app/getApps1
api/services/AppStore/getApps1

api/services/app/getApps2
api/services/AppStore/getApps2

api/services/app/getApps3
api/services/AppStore/getApps3
```

Comment: Can you just call action.Selectors.Add() to add another selector for that action?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `action.Selectors.Add()`. Currently you are simply overwriting the default selector(s) with your custom route. Also I think your logic is slightly flawed. You are overwriting `templatePrefix`, but then you claim that you in fact want both routes to be registered.

You can try something similar to the following:

```
public static void Map(ControllerModel model)
{
    string templatePrefix = "api/services/app";
    ...
    foreach (var action in model.Actions)
    {
        var verb = ProxyScriptingHelper.GetConventionalVerbForMethodName(action.ActionName);
        var constraint = new HttpMethodActionConstraint(new List<string> { verb });

        foreach (var selector in action.Selectors)
        {
            selector.ActionConstraints.Add(constraint);
            selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel(new RouteAttribute($"{templatePrefix.EnsureEndsWith('/')}{action.Controller.ControllerName}/{action.ActionName}"));
        }
    if (AppStore.Contains(model.ControllerName))
            {
                templatePrefix = "api/services/AppStore";
                var sm = new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel(new RouteAttribute(
                        $"{templatePrefix.EnsureEndsWith('/')}{action.Controller.ControllerName}/{action.ActionName}"))
                };
                sm.ActionConstraints.Add(constraint);
                action.Selectors.Add(sm);
            }
    }
}
```